Could not start a new session on Jenkins server
I have an issue with creating session on server while trying to run automated tests [Java + selenium] - for Firefox and Chrome. Locally tests work fine but not on provided to me Jenkins server. Unfortunately I don’t know much about it’s configuration so I’m stuck. At first I had many proxy issues, but now I don’t know what to do next. I asked and chrome and firefox should be installed on server

[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 1.763 s <<< FAILURE! - in XXX.Tests.LoginTests
[ERROR] XXX.Tests.LoginTests.beforeTest Time elapsed: 1.485 s <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
Host info: host: ‘PFALT224183’, ip: ‘10.61.224.183’
Build info: version: ‘4.21.0’, revision: ‘79ed462ef4’
System info: os.name: ‘Linux’, os.arch: ‘amd64’, os.version: ‘6.2.0-1018-azure’, java.version: ‘17.0.9’
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {binary: /usr/bin/firefox}}]}]

For Chrome:

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn’t exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Host info: host: ‘PFALT224183’, ip: ‘10.61.224.183’
Build info: version: ‘4.21.0’, revision: ‘79ed462ef4’
System info: os.name: ‘Linux’, os.arch: ‘amd64’, os.version: ‘6.2.0-1018-azure’, java.version: ‘17.0.9’
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: , binary: /usr/bin/google-chrome, extensions: }}]}]
at

How can I fix it? I don't have access to the server so I need to go to my admins with possible solutions and they say everything should be fine :D
